# bootstrap-select - label and dropdown select box align vertical, not horizontal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I've read and read, and tried tons of stuff, and I'm about to pull out what remains of my hair and could use some advice or another set of eyes:

Using bootstrap 3.3.7, and I have a dropdown box which is working and the styling is fine, **but the label *AND* the dropdown appear next to one another**.

So instead of :

LINE#  *PRODUCT*          QTY

1      *[Mechanical]*      10       [labels on one row, values on one row]

...i get:

LINE#  *PRODUCT*     [*Mechanical*] [product label *AND* dropdown on same row]

```
                            QTY
```

1                               10

The LABEL and the DROPDOWN next to each other on the same line, instead of the *LABEL on the same level as the other LABELs*, and the DROPDOWN on the same row as the rest of the form input fields.

```
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>  
        <script src="http://localhost/f1x/wp-content/themes/MyProduct/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>  
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/f1x/wp-content/themes/MyProduct/css/bootstrap.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/f1x/wp-content/themes/MyProduct/css/bootstrap_extend.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/f1x/wp-content/themes/MyProduct/css/bootstrap-select.css' />            

    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
          ...
        </header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="form">
                        <div class="col-xs-16 col-md-16">                             
                            <div class="row" id="entryrow">
                                <div class="col-xs-01" id="lin">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="lin">LIN#</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="lin" readonly class="form-control" placeholder="1">
                                </div>                                     
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="prd_" class="col-lg-2 control-label">PRODUCT</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2" class="selectpicker control-label">
                                        <select id="prd_" class="form-control" name="prd_">
                                            <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                            <option value="service">Structural Square</option>
                                            <option value="suggestions">Structural Rectangular</option>
                                            <option value="support">Pipe</option>
                                            <option value="support">Mechanical Square</option>
                                            <option value="support">Mechanical Rectangular</option>
                                            <option value="support">Mechanical Round</option>
                                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                      
                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <label for="qty_" class="control-label">QTY</label>                                          
                                    <input type="text" id="qty_" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
                                </div>[bootstrap dropdown horizontal, not vertical][1]
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/48975bo7/

Comment: cleaned it up and it works here:  https://jsfiddle.net/ughgaL6b/

Answer (score 0):

From your fiddle:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="prd_" class="col-lg-2 control-label">PRODUCT</label><br>
  <div class="col-lg-2" class="selectpicker control-label">
    <select id="prd_" class="form-control" name="prd_">
      <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
      <option value="service">Structural Square</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have a few issues with your styling here. Namely, your col size usage isn't consistent. There was also an instance of classes being defined twice within one element. I've added col-md and adjusted your col-xs sizes so that they add to 12. I've also removed your col-lg-2 sizes being used in the product dropdown as they're disrupting the display on larger screens. Based on your question I believe this is what you were trying to achieve:

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94n6q7md/)